# When changing an image in one place how can I have it reflect the changes in other places in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I've got 2 questions.

1. I’ve got an image as a button so when you tap it you can choose an image from your image roll. When I go to another view and then come back the image is gone. How can I keep it from disappearing when I change views in SwiftUI?
2. How can I link it to the other UIImages within the app so that when you change the image in the one spot it reflects the changes in the other places? Right now the top image is hard coded but I want it to reflect what the smaller image is showing. I've added a picture below to show what I'm talking about or you can view a video of it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubpkfig1lpil9px/Profile.mov?dl=0).

[image: Profile]

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: View {

    @State var isShowingImagePicker = false

    @State var imageInBlackCircle = UIImage()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isShowingImagePicker.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(uiImage: imageInBlackCircle)
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle() .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 3, x: 0, y: 3)
                    .frame(width: 60.0, height: 70.0)
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)

                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker, content: {
                        ImagePickerView(isPresented: self.$isShowingImagePicker, selectedImage: self.$imageInBlackCircle)
                    })
            }
        }
    }

    struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

        @Binding var isPresented: Bool
        @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage

        func makeUIViewController(context:
            UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerView>) ->
            UIViewController {
                let controller = UIImagePickerController()
                controller.delegate = context.coordinator
                return controller
        }

        func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerView.Coordinator {
            return Coordinator(parent: self)
        }

        class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

            let parent: ImagePickerView
            init(parent: ImagePickerView) {
                self.parent = parent
            }

            func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                if let selectedImageFromPicker = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                    print(selectedImageFromPicker)
                    self.parent.selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker
                }

                self.parent.isPresented = false
            }
        }


        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePickerView.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerView>) {

        }
    }

    struct ImagePicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ImagePicker()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you now know the usage of `@State`. They are properties of special kind those help `SwiftUI` views to reload in case of any change in their values. This ensures synchronization. So if you need to link this property to other places as well, you need to pass around this property, right? But by design:

> `@State` is great for simple properties that belong to a specific view and **never get used outside that view**, so as a result it’s important to mark those properties as being **private** to re-enforce the idea that such state is specifically designed never to escape its view.

---

So what do we have? Pay attention:

> For more complex properties – when you have a custom type you want to use that might have multiple properties and methods, or **might be shared across multiple views** – you should use `@ObservedObject` instead.

You can read more from [What’s the difference between @ObservedObject, @State, and @EnvironmentObject?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject)

Does the above make sense? If yes, you need this `@ObservedObject`. Let's see how do we achieve that.

You declare an object that conforms to `ObservableObject`. You mark those properties with `@Published` wrapper so that any instance of the said `ObservableObject` gets notified of change made to that property.

```
import Combine
import UIKit

class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image = UIImage()
}
```

Now, you need an instance of this object somewhere so that you can observe its state. That's where you'll make use of `@ObservedObject` wrapper.

```
struct ImagePicker: View {
    @State private var isShowingImagePicker = false // make this private
    @State private var isShowingDetailView = false // make this private

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = UserViewModel() // either you initialize this here, 
                                                    // or inject this from somewhere else
}
```

Then, when you initialize other views, for showing/presenting, you just pass around the `@ObservedObject` property. Like:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(userViewModel: viewModel), isActive: $isShowingDetailView) {
    Text("Detail")
}
```

Where your `DetailView` will be somewhat like:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var userViewModel: UserViewModel // you may need to declare this as @ObservedObject as well if you are required to manipulate state of UserViewModel from this view
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: userViewModel.image)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

---

For your simple case, this should be enough. But if you need to have access to the stateful object from anywhere down the view hierarchy, you may want to look at `@EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/M-I-N/ImageObservable) is a demo implementation slightly different than your configuration.

Comment: You can go [here](https://github.com/CoryT87/Test) and see what I've got. When you tap the profile tab and change the image there I would like for it to change on the same screen as well as on the home tab. Also, I would like for it to stay and not disappear when you change tabs or close the app out. I tried what you suggested but I couldn't get it to work for me.

Comment: And your comment ___Also, I would like for it to stay and not disappear when you change tabs___ would play nice if you have studied what I've said with the last line **For your simple case, this should be enough. But if you need to have access to the stateful object from anywhere down the view hierarchy, you may want to look at `@EnvironmentObject`.** Once you've the solution of my previous comment, I would recommend you study a little bit about `@EnvironmentObject`. Actually you would have a good idea if you had gone through the link I attached in my answer.

Comment: The last thing you've asked for ___close the app out___. This is something that isn't related to this question. You need to have some kind of **persistent storage** for that to achieve. That would require you to study storage options available for iOS. When you are ready for incorporating those options, you are welcome to come back to StackOverflow and ask your question if there is any. Good luck!

Comment: I did look through the link you provided but when you tap the circle it goes to another page then you have to tap the circle again to change the image. What I’m doing you only have to tap the circle to change the image.

Comment: You didn't get my point. I was talking about the [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) in my answer not the demo implementation attached in my comment.